# hive hadoop permissions not correct

Tags: hadoop, hive, ubuntu-14.04, kylin

I installed apache kylin which requires Hadoop, hove, hbase and java to work. All things are installed correctly. Now when I try to run [this](http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/tutorial/kylin_sample.html) example. I get error after the first command ie **${KYLIN_HOME}/bin/sample.sh**

and below is the error I am getting

`Loading data to table default.kylin_sales
Failed with exception Unable to move source file:/usr/lib/kylin/sample_cube/data/DEFAULT.KYLIN_SALES.csv to destination hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hive/warehouse/kylin_sales/DEFAULT.KYLIN_SALES.csv
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask`

I have set 777 permissions for both the above path and I am operating as root

Answer (score 0):

Check the hdfs directory permission. If it is not like below, change permission like below

`hdfs dfs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse`